# confusion about lastIndexOf in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 var a="bananas";
 a.lastIndexOf("a",1)  /// output is 1
 a.lastIndexOf("a",2)  /// output is 1
 a.lastIndexOf("a",4)  /// output is 3
```

Can anyone explain me how output is coming 1 for both the cases
I know it is trying to matches from last end but I am unable to understand the logic from official doc

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the paragraph about **Definition and Usage** on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp)

The lastIndexOf() method returns the position of the last occurrence of a specified value in a string.

> This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.
>
> **Note**: The lastIndexOf() method is case sensitive!
>
> Tip: Also look at the [indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method.

---

**Syntax**

> string.indexOf(*searchvalue, start*)

**Parameter Values**

> search (*Required*) The **string to search for** start
>
> value  (*Optional, default: 0*) At which **position to start** the search

---

**Your example:**

```
var a = "bananas";
a.lastIndexOf("a",1)  // output is 1
a.lastIndexOf("a",4)  // output is 3
```

`a.lastIndexOf("a",1)` will search for the last 'a' in bananas whose index <= 1.

What this means is that it will return the last location of an a in 'ba'.

So `a.lastIndexOf("a",4)` will search for the last a in 'bana'.

It's indeed somehow confusing. But keep in mind that the *value* parameter will actually trim the string at the given position as the function will search backwards from that location.

Answer (score -1):

The lastIndexOf() method returns the position of the last occurrence of a specified value in a string.

**Definition and Usage**

```
string.lastIndexOf(searchvalue, start)
```

**Parameter**

- *searchvalue* (Required) The string to search for
- *start*  (Optional) The position where to start the search (searching backwards). If omitted, the default value is the length of the string

Answer (score -1):

`lastIndexOf()` search backwards so in your example, the counter would be as follows:

```
b a n a n a s
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
            ^
```

.lastIndexOf('a', 1) would be 1 because starting at position 1 and we see first 'a' at position 1

```
b a n a n a s
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
      ^
  3 2 1
```

.lastIndexOf('a', 4) would be 3 because starting at position 4, we see first 'a' at position 3.

Comment: Your answer is totally wrong. If we had this example  ```"apple dpple is my apple".lastIndexOf("apple", 6)``` location of "apple" based on your reasoning, it would be 6, which is incorrect. It counts from 0 to the end. "apple" would be at 0.

Comment: @Behnam The question asked with search value of one char thus the simplified example to show Danny what it did. The counter (!== index) is specifically named this way to explain the function traverse backward and counts along based on the UNIT of search value. You misread and assumed I'm writing a working function.